# Prove that $\frac{ a^2 +b^2 +c^2}{d^2}$ is always greater than $\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: geometry, polygons

Prove that if $a,b,c$ and $d$ are the sides of a quadrilateral ,then the value of

$\frac{ a^2 +b^2 +c^2}{d^2}$ is always greater than $\frac{1}{3}$

Could someone please give me hint to solve this problem.

Comment: You must have $d<a+b+c$

Comment: Are the sides integer?

Comment: @almagest These are sides of a quadrilateral, so that must be true.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Obviously, but he wanted a hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $a+b+c\geq d$ and $$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\leq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}$$Stitch these two inequalities together, and you're done.

Comment: Can you please give an explanation about the inequality...

Comment: @tatan the first one comes from the fact that $a,b,c,d$ are sides in a quadrilateral. The second one is an inequality known by the name "arithmetic mean-quadratic mean inequality" (am-qm for short), or "root mean square-arithmetic mean inequality".

Comment: @Arthur  I didn't had knowledge of this arithmetic mean-quadratic mean inequality. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Mathematics If you're into inequalities, there are a few that should be committed to memory. One is the entire chain of harmonic-geometric-arithmetic-quadratic means. The other really important one is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: @Arthur The second inequality is also the C-S: $$(a+b+c)^2 \leq (1^2+1^2+1^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

Comment: @N.S. Which just goes to show that the CS inequality is really important. I have heard it said that in competition problems, _any_ inequality can supposedly be reduced to CS. While that might not be true, it is not far from. It can, however, be a bit unwieldy at times.

Answer (score 5):

As in the comment, $d < a + b +c$. From this:
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{d^2}>\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2 +2 a b+2 ac+2bc}\geq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+\left(a^2+c^2\right)+\left(b^2+c^2\right)+(a^2+b^2)}=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: @tatan The denominator of the second to last term is $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$, i.e., three time the numerator.

Comment: @Taozi Why do you use *less than sign* ?

Comment: @Taozi if $0<x<y$ then $1/x^2 > 1/y^2$

Comment: For the ones wondering: this proof uses $d\leq a+b+c$ and the fact that a square is positive: $(a-b)^2\geq0\implies a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$ (this may also be interpreted as a special case of the _rearrangement inequality_).

Comment: @tatan Hi, I am sorry for the mistake, and won't hurry next time :-(

Comment: @ComplexPhi, thanks a lot for your edit!

Comment: @Arthur I made a mistake before (fixed by ComplexPhi), but thanks for your input.